# Elementary method to compute $\zeta (3)$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, zeta-functions

What is an elementary method to compute $\zeta (3)$ which can be understood by a high school student? I know how to compute $\zeta (2)$ but not $\zeta (3)$.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by "to compute $\zeta(3)$"? What would be the desirable form of the answer?

Answer (score 4):

By definition
$$
\zeta(3)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac1{n^3}
$$
This can be used to compute $\zeta(3)$, but the convergence is fairly slow (you'd need to sum $200,000$ terms to get $10$ places).

There are ways to [accelerate the convergence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration) such as [Euler's transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_acceleration#Euler.27s_transform). The [Euler-Maclaurin Sum Formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Maclaurin_formula) can also be used to accelerate the series. However, these acceleration methods are probably beyond most high school students (Euler's transform might be accessible).

Comment: Also, whereas the value of $\zeta(2)$ has a nice closed form, the same cannot be said for $\zeta(3)$ in the sense that we do not know if such a nice closed form exists or not (although presumably it does not)

Comment: @AndrewD: It is true that [Apéry's Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ap%C3%A9ry%27s_constant) is irrational, but it is not known if it is transcendental. Furthermore, $$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{(2k+1)^3}=\frac78\zeta(3)
$$
but
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}
$$

Comment: @robjohn Wow! Great comparison! I have seen the first one but never the second one. Can I ask where you found the second equation?

Comment: @zeta: I wrote [this paper](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78279253/zeta-beta.pdf) which gives recurrence relations for $\zeta(2n)$ and $\beta(2n+1)$.

Comment: The dropbox site linked above is no longer accessible. [This answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613341) has the same information on the [Dirichlet Beta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function).