# Proving that $\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}=1-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k(2k+1)\zeta(2k+2)}{4^{2k+2}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, riemann-zeta, pi, constants

After numerical analysis it seems that

$$
\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}=1-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k(2k+1)\zeta(2k+2)}{4^{2k+2}}
$$

Could someone prove the validity of such identity?

Comment: There are lots and lots of identities of this type. Have you read answers to your [previous question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/611869/)? This one can be solved in exactly the same manner. What have you tried anyway?

Comment: You must be right, there are lots of this kind of identities. And I was wondering if there is a more general formula. For exemple we have the following 
$$
\frac{\pi}{2}=1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\eta(2k)}{2^{2k}}
$$
and
$$
\frac{\pi}{3}=1+2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{\eta(2k)}{6^{2k}}
$$
and in this line of thought how coud we express $\pi/5$ or $\pi/7$?

Comment: @Grigory, I can prove some of this formulas but not all of them so when I can't I ask here.

Comment: @Grigori, can you provide a formula for $\pi/7$ involving $\zeta$ or $\eta$ whatever you like?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand — certainly you won't be satisfied $\frac27(1+2\sum\eta(2k)2^{-2k})$ — but what's the question exactly then? Anyway, first question is, what is $\sum\zeta(2k)x^{2k}$ and $\sum\eta(2k)x^{2k}$ — do you happen to know answers?

Comment: @Grigory, I'm looking for a formula similar to $\pi/5=1\pm m\sum_{k} \frac{\eta(f(k))}{n^{f(k)}}$.

Comment: @Grigory, ... but it would be acceptable to replace $\eta$ with $\zeta$.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Yes, we can prove it. We can change the order of summation in

$$\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k(2k+1)\zeta(2k+2)}{4^{2k+2}}
&= \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k(2k+1)}{4^{2k+2}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^{2k+2}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k(2k+1)}{(4n)^{2k+2}}\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty r''(4n),
\end{align}$$

where, for $\lvert z\rvert > 1$, we define

$$r(z) = \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{z^{2k}} = \frac{1}{z^2-1} = \frac12\left(\frac{1}{z-1} - \frac{1}{z+1}\right).$$

Differentiating yields $r''(z) = \frac{1}{(z-1)^3} - \frac{1}{(z+1)^3}$, so

$$1 - \sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{2k(2k+1)\zeta(2k+2)}{4^{2k+2}} = \sum_{\nu = 0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^\nu}{(2\nu+1)^3},$$

and the latter sum is [by an earlier answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/581202/83702) using the partial fraction decomposition of $\dfrac{1}{\cos z}$:

$$\sum_{\nu=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^\nu}{(2\nu+1)^3} = - \frac{\pi^3}{32} E_2 = \frac{\pi^3}{32}.$$

Comment: I took too long to move my recursion for $\beta(2k+1)$ from [my pdf](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/78279253/zeta-beta.pdf), and I didn't take time to realize that the first part of my answer is almost the same as your answer. I hope you don't mind if I leave my answer; I would like to have the recursion for $\beta(2k+1)$ on site.

Comment: Not at all, au contraire. Thanks for the link, that'll come handy to look the values and recursions up.

Answer (score 29):

Using the formula for a geometric series,
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac1{x^{2k}}
&=\frac1{x^2-1}\\
&=\frac12\left(\frac1{x-1}-\frac1{x+1}\right)\tag{1}
\end{align}
$$
Differentiating $(1)$ twice,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k(2k+1)}{x^{2k+2}}
=\frac1{(x-1)^3}-\frac1{(x+1)^3}\tag{2}
$$
Changing the order of summation and applying $(2)$,
$$
\begin{align}
1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k(2k+1)\zeta(2k+2)}{4^{2k+2}}
&=1-\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty\frac{2k(2k+1)}{(4j)^{2k+2}}\\
&=1-\sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{2k(2k+1)}{(4j)^{2k+2}}\\
&=1-\sum_{j=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{(4j-1)^3}-\frac1{(4j+1)^3}\right)\\
&=1-\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(2n+1)^3}\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^3}\tag{3}
\end{align}
$$
The sum in $(3)$ can be generalized as
$$
\beta(s)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)^s}\tag{4}
$$
and is known as the [Dirichlet beta function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function). As shown below, $\beta(3)=\dfrac{\pi^3}{32}$.

---

We can develop a recurrence for $\beta(2k+1)$. First, the generating function for $\beta(2k+1)$ is
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \beta(2k+1) x^{2k+1}\\
     &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^\infty (-1)^n\left(\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)^{2k+1}\\
     &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{\frac{x}{2n+1}}{1-\left(\frac{x}{2n+1}\right)^2}\\
     &= \frac{x}{2} \sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n \left(\frac{1}{2n+1+x}+\frac{1}{2n+1-x}\right)\\
     &= \frac{x}{2} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{2n+1+x}\\
     &= \frac{x}{4} \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \frac{1}{n+\tfrac{1+x}{2}}\\
     &= \frac{x}{4} \pi \csc\left(\pi\tfrac{1+x}{2}\right)\\[3pt]
     &= \frac{\pi}{4} x \sec\left(\frac{\pi}{2}x\right)\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
where we use $(7)$ from [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/143179) to get
$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{n+z}
&=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac2{2n+z}-\sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac1{n+z}\\[3pt]
&=\pi\cot(\pi z/2)-\pi\cot(\pi z)\\[9pt]
&=\pi\csc(\pi z)\tag{6}
\end{align}
$$
We can use equation $(5)$ to develop a recurrence relation:
$$
\begin{align}
\frac{\pi}{4} x
&= \cos\left(\frac{\pi}{2} x\right) f(x)\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \frac{(\frac{\pi}{2} x)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\;\beta(2n-2k+1)x^{2n-2k+1}\\
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty\sum_{k=0}^n \frac{(-\pi^2/4)^k}{(2k)!}\;\beta(2n-2k+1)x^{2n+1}\tag{7}
\end{align}
$$
For $n=0$, we can use the arctan series to get
$$
\beta(1) = \frac{\pi}{4}\tag{8}
$$
and for $n\gt0$, $(7)$ gives
$$
\beta(2n+1) = -\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{(-\pi^2/4)^k}{(2k)!}\;\beta(2n-2k+1)\tag{9}
$$
Recursion $(9)$ yields
$$
\begin{align}
\beta(1)&=\frac{\pi}{4}\\
\beta(3)&=\frac{\pi^3}{32}\\
\beta(5)&=\frac{5\pi^5}{1536}\\
\beta(7)&=\frac{61\pi^7}{184320}\\
\beta(9)&=\frac{277\pi^9}{8257536}\\
\beta(11)&=\frac{50521\pi^{11}}{14863564800}\\
\beta(13)&=\frac{540553\pi^{13}}{1569592442880}\\
\beta(15)&=\frac{199360981\pi^{15}}{5713316492083200}\\
\beta(17)&=\frac{3878302429\pi^{17}}{1096956766479974400}\\
\beta(19)&=\frac{2404879675441\pi^{19}}{6713375410857443328000}
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Excellent job! (+1)

Comment: would the downvoter care to comment?

Comment: by (7), I get $$\frac{\pi}{4}x=\beta(1)x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[x^{2n+1}\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^k\frac{(\pi x/2)^{2k}}{(2k)!}\beta(2n-2k+1)\right]=\frac{\pi}{4}x+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[x^{2n+1}\left[\beta(2n+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-\frac{\pi^2}{4})^k}{(2k)!}\beta(2n-2k+1)\right]\right]$$ so $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\left[x^{2n+1}\left[\beta(2n+1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-\frac{\pi^2}{4})^k}{(2k)!}\beta(2n-2k+1)\right]\right]=0.$$ then how to get (9) please? maybe it is: if $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}x^{2n+1}g(n)=0$, then we have $g(n)=0$. I can not prove it, could you explain it to me in detail please?

Comment: @xunitc: The sum on the left is a polynomial which is equal to $0$. That means that each coefficient of $x^{2n+1}$ must be $0$. $(9)$ follows by using this fact.

Comment: Thank you, I know it now, it converges to $0$, and can make differentiation of x, then the coefficient is $0$.

Answer (score 8):

Starting from the [Laurent series of the cotangent function](http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf):
$$\pi z\cot \left( \pi z \right) =1-2\,\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }\zeta 
 \left( 2\,k+2 \right) {z}^{2k+2} \tag{1}$$
apply the differential operator:
$$\hat{D}=z^2\dfrac{d^2}{dz^2}-2z\dfrac{d}{dz}+2 \tag{2}$$
to get:
$${z}^{3}{\pi }^{3}\cot \left( \pi z \right)  \left( 1+ \cot
 \left( \pi z \right)   ^{2} \right) =1-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }2k \left( 2k+1 \right)
\,\zeta  \left( 2\,k+2 \right) {z}^{2k+2}\tag{3}$$
which, by the ratio test, has a radius of convergence of $|z|<1$. Then from:
$$z=\dfrac{1}{4}, \quad \cot\left(\dfrac{\pi}{4}\right)=1 \tag{4}$$
we have:
$$\dfrac{{\pi }^{3}}{32}=1-\sum _{k=0}^{\infty }{\frac {2k \left( 2\,k+1
 \right) \zeta  \left( 2\,k+2 \right) }{{4}^{2k+2}}}\tag{5}$$

Answer (score 1):

$$ 
\begin{align} 
S\, &=\,\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k\,(2k+1)\,\zeta(2k+2)}{4^{2k+2}} \,=\,\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(2k+1)!\,\zeta(2k+2)}{(2k-1)!\,4^{2k+2}} \\[4mm] 
&=\,\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(1/4)^{2k+2}}{(2k-1)!}\,\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^{2k+1}}{e^x-1}\,dx \,=\,4^{-3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^x-1}\,\left(\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{(x/4)^{2k-1}}{(2k-1)!}\right)\,dx \\[4mm] 
&=\,4^{-3}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{e^x-1}\,\sinh\left(\frac{x}{4}\right)\,dx \,=\,\frac{4^{-3}}{2}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{1-e^{-x}}\,\left({\Large e}^{-\frac34x}\,-\,{\Large e}^{-\frac54x}\right)\,dx \\[4mm] 
&=\,4^{-3}\left[\zeta\left(3,\frac34\right)\,-\,\zeta\left(3,\frac54\right)\right] \,=\,1-4^{-3}\left[\zeta\left(3,\frac14\right)\,-\,\zeta\left(3,\frac34\right)\right] \\[4mm] 
&=\,1-\beta(3) \,=\,{\color\red{1-\frac{\pi^3}{32}}} \\ 
\end{align} 
$$

$\,\zeta(s,q) \,\,$ : [Hurwitz Zeta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hurwitz_zeta_function)
$\,\beta(s)\quad\,$ : [Dirichlet Beta Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_beta_function)