# Planning to integrate $\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2(x)}{x^2 + 1} dx$ using complex analysis

Tags: calculus, integration, sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, contour-integration

This is just a plan-out.

I want to evaluate:

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{\log^2(x)}{x^2 + 1} dx$$

Using a keyhole contour a semi-circle, with base at the x-axis.

**First I must pick a branch.**

Since the logarithm is multivalued in that,

$$\log(e^{i2\pi}) = \log(e^{(2ki\pi) +  i2\pi})$$

We consider: $f(z)  = \displaystyle \frac{\log^2(z)}{z^2 + 1}$

But how should I pick a branch.

**(1) What is a "Branch?"**

(2) Should I pick a place where the $\log$ is continous. That is everywhere except $z=0$

So then my contour will be **half-washer shape.** with the opening in the middle:
 [Half a Washer](http://www.hellotrade.com/daco-precision-tool/mb-half-washer-specialty-washers.html)

Thanks

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1030246/evaluate-int-0-infty-frac-log-x21x2-dx-using-complex-analysis/1030272#1030272