# Calculating the infinite sum ${1\over 1^3} - {1\over 3^3} + {1\over 5^3} + ...$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, taylor-expansion

I came across the set of problems

> $$
> \begin{split}
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{2k+1}
>  &= \frac11 &- \frac13 &+ \frac15 &\pm \ldots &= \frac{\pi}{4}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^2}
>  &= \frac1{1^2} &+ \frac1{3^2} &+ \frac1{5^2} &+ \ldots &= \frac{\pi^2}{8}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^3}
>  &= \frac1{1^3} &- \frac1{3^3} &+ \frac1{5^2} &\pm \ldots &= \frac{\pi^3}{32}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^4}
>  &= \frac1{1^4} &+ \frac1{3^4} &+ \frac1{5^4} &+ \ldots &= \frac{\pi^4}{96}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)^5}
>  &= \frac1{1^5} &- \frac1{3^5} &+ \frac1{5^5} &\pm \ldots &= \frac{5\pi^5}{1536}\\
> \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{1}{(2k+1)^6}
>  &= \frac1{1^6} &+ \frac1{3^6} &+ \frac1{5^6} &+ \ldots &= \frac{\pi^6}{960}
> \end{split}
> $$

I was able to do the first one using Maclaurin series of $\tan x$ , and also I was able to compute the ones with even powers by comparing coefficient of various powers of x in two different expressions for $\sin x$ , one from Maclaurin expansion and the other by forming a polynomial with roots {${...,-2\pi,-\pi,0,\pi,2\pi,...}$} (i.e. Euler's Method)

But I have no idea how to compute the ones with odd powers , I searched a lot too , but nowhere could I find any way to compute the ones with odd powers.

Could someone please guide me on how to compute the ones with odd powers ?

And also shorter ways of computing the ones with even powers are highly welcomed.

Thanks

Comment: See this answer (the one by robjohn): https://math.stackexchange.com/a/613341/323432