# Prove $\sum\limits_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{(2r-1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, summation, proof-writing

I would like to know how to prove that
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{(2r-1)^3}=\frac{\pi^3}{32}$$
I would very much prefer answers that avoid non-elementary functions like the gamma or beta functions, as although I am researching them, I am still in high school and not very familiar with them- but if it is necessary, I will not object :)

I know how to prove the Basel problem using $\sin$ expressed as a product of its factors and its Maclaurin series, and other similar series, such as
$$\sum_{r=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{r+1}}{r^2}=\frac{\pi^2}{12}$$
but I cannot find a similar method to help evaluate this. It'd also be helpful if I could find an elementary function that I could express as a useful series expansion and then integrate between $0$ and $1$ to evaluate the series I am dealing with such as
$$\frac{1}{1^2}-\frac{x^2}{3^2}+\frac{x^4}{5^2}-\frac{x^6}{7^2}+\cdots$$
but I cannot find any function that has this series expansion.

Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think Fourier theory is the way to go for the sum, but this is probably beyond your current knowledge. I don't know an elementary proof (with high school methods), but that could possibly exist of course.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3629848/calculating-the-infinite-sum-1-over-13-1-over-33-1-over-53?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613152/proving-that-frac-pi332-1-sum-k-1-infty-frac2k2k1-zeta2k2/613341#613341

Comment: My idea would be the following: take $${(1-x^2)}^{-1}=1-x^2+x^4..$$ intgrate then divide equation by  $x$ again integrate bothsides and then again divide by $x$ and then again integrate and then divide by $x$ finally put $x=1$ ...ugly isnt it?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore thanks for the idea. However, that wouldn't result in an elementary function though; you'd have to integrate $$\frac{\text{artanh$x$}}{x}$$

Comment: @A-LevelStudent exactly thats why i didnt write it as an answer.....:)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1852754/814070 may help.

Comment: Imo the most fun solution is to use  $\sum (-1)^n/(2n-1)$ and use 3 dimensional diagonal summation. Even more fun is if you first show $\zeta(2)$ but then with 2d diagonal summation. But writing it out takes some time

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proving that $\frac{\pi^{3}}{32}=1-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{2k(2k+1)\zeta(2k+2)}{4^{2k+2}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/613152/proving-that-frac-pi332-1-sum-k-1-infty-frac2k2k1-zeta2k2)

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/359667/sum-sum-n-0-infty-frac-1n2n13/359687#359687